# Is [NSManagedObjectContext performBlock] synchronous if run on the context's thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Say I have a managed object context tied to the main thread, and I call `[mainContext performBlock:block]` on the main thread. Will that run synchronously or is it still scheduled and run at a later time?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` (and not `NSConfinementConcurrencyType`), calling `performBlock:` behaves like `dispatch_async`, i.e. your block will be *enqueued* and not be executed immediately.

You can verify this easily:

```
NSLog(@"before block");
[self.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"in block");
}];
NSLog(@"after block");
```

This will print (in that order):

```
before block
after block
in block
```

If you need to perform a block synchronously, you have to use `performBlockAndWait:` for both queue-based concurrency types.

Comment: I actually meant NSConfinementConcurrencyType, I just happened to choose the main thread as the thread that the context is confined to. Does it make a difference?

Comment: You can't use `performBlock:` with `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` at all. It'll throw an exception.

Comment: Apologies for all my confusion. Why can't `performBlock:` be used with `NSConfinementConcurrencyType`? It seems logical that if you have a context confined to a thread, you'd want to be able to perform blocks on its thread. Is the issue that `NSManagedObjectContext` doesn't know how to invoke blocks on a user-created thread?

Comment: Threads and queues are not the same thing. Blocks are performed on queues, not threads. When you use `NSConfinementConcurrencyType`, there is no queue that the block could be executed on.